# Rebuilding a driver for a different kernel version

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers

I have an os with the kernel version of about 3.3 and the driver requires the kernel to be at least 4.4, there's no way to upgrade due to hardware limitations.

would it be feasible to just change the configuration of the driver or would I have to build it from scratch?

Comment: You'll have to get the source code of the driver, modify it for the earlier kernel version (the hard part), and compile it. However, I doubt that you can't upgrade to 4.4 "due to hardware limitations" - properly configured, a 4.4 kernel should work fine even with old hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface between the core of the Linux kernel and drivers evolves very quickly. You may of course be lucky and find that the interfaces that the driver uses have remained mostly compatible, but chances are that the interfaces have changed a lot and porting a driver across 4 years of kernel development would be difficult.

Unless you need to support both newer hardware and some antique hardware that recent kernels no longer support, compile a 4.4 kernel. The interfaces between the kernel and applications are extremely stable. You should be able to replace any kernel since 2.0 or so by a newer kernel on any Linux system.